# Unity Animator component unnecessarily overriding scripted position of Game Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development, animator

I have a hand and pistol(fps) gameObject. and the recoil system is controlled directly from script (including the slide on the pistol) and it works perfectly.
the moment I added an idle and reload animation the pistol slider stops moving back when recoiling.
When I disable the animator component it works back fine, I even deleted all my keyframes on the "idle" animation still the slider doesn't work.

I have my Recoil Script below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponRecoil : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float recoilX;
    [SerializeField]
    private float recoilY;
    [SerializeField]
    private float recoilZ;
    [SerializeField]
    private float recoilResetSpeed = 0.8f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float snappiness = 2f;

    public Transform parent;
    Vector3 targetRotation;
    Vector3 currentRotation;
    Vector3 targetHandPosition;
    Vector3 currentHandPosition;
   
    [SerializeField]
    private List<EjectorData> bulletEjectors;
    [SerializeField]
    float ejectorBackDistance;
    [SerializeField]
    float ejectorReturnSpeed=10;

    void Start() {
        foreach (EjectorData ejector in bulletEjectors)
        {
            ejector.startPosition = ejector.obj.localPosition;
        }
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        coolDownWeaponRecoilEffect();
    }

    void coolDownWeaponRecoilEffect()
    {
        targetRotation = Vector3.Lerp(targetRotation, Vector3.zero, recoilResetSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        currentRotation = Vector3.Slerp(currentRotation, targetRotation, snappiness * Time.deltaTime);
        //resetting the pushback effect of the recoil of the hand
        targetHandPosition = Vector3.Lerp(targetHandPosition, Vector3.zero, recoilResetSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        currentHandPosition = Vector3.Slerp(currentHandPosition, targetHandPosition, snappiness * Time.deltaTime);

        if (parent == null) return;
        parent.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
        transform.localPosition = currentHandPosition;

        //resseting the bullet ejectors back to their normal positions
        foreach (EjectorData ejector in bulletEjectors)
        {
            ejector.obj.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(ejector.obj.localPosition, ejector.startPosition, ejectorReturnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }

    public void Recoil() {
        targetRotation += new Vector3(recoilX, Random.Range(-recoilY, recoilY), 0);
        targetHandPosition -= new Vector3(0, 0, recoilZ);
        foreach (EjectorData ejector in bulletEjectors) {
            ejector.obj.localPosition -= new Vector3(0, 0, ejectorBackDistance);
        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    class EjectorData {
        public Transform obj;
        public Vector3 startPosition;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put is simply your script is overriding the position of the bones, and the animator is overriding that; rendering it useless

To change the bones **rotation/Position** on top the animation you should look into Unity's [Animation Rigging](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-animation-rigging)

[AnimationRigging](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-animation-rigging) works as a **post-process step** of the Animator and has the same restrictions as any animated hierarchy. you can use the `Override Transform Constraint` To achieve the effect you are looking for.

[this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JD7iDleSzDA) might help you a bit if you are stuck.